# How to find out my site is being scraped?

Tags: web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

How to find out my site is being scraped?

I've some points...

1. Network Bandwidth occupation, causing throughput problems (matches if proxy used).
2. When querting search engine for key words the new referrences appear to other similar resources with the same content (matches if proxy used).
3. Multiple requesting from the same IP.
4. High requests rate from a single IP. (by the way: What is a normal rate?)
5. Headless or weird user agent (matches if proxy used).
6. Requesting with predictable (equal) intervals from the same IP.
7. Certain support files are never requested, ex. favicon.ico, various CSS and javascript files (matches if proxy used).
8. The client's requests sequence. Ex. client access not directly accessible pages (matches if proxy used).

Would you add more to this list?

What points might fit/match if a scraper uses proxying?

Comment: Related: [Can page scraping be detected?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6936453) and [The way to detect web scraping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5372115). Basically it is quite hard to determine, since they use different approaches to confuse.

Comment: From personal experience - the rate at which a single IP visits your site will very quite widely based on your website. For example I once had a website I created that it would be average to visit once per day and view only a few pages (since we posted information only once a day). Other websites (say forums, or dynamically updating websites with lots of information posted frequently) you might expect a much more random assortment of visits. Or if your website is consistent, it would be very infrequent - maybe 1-2 per day, then falls off.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to detect scrapers? Most sites are in favour of it - scraping is exactly how you get into search engines. If your intention is to block it, have you tried the robots exclusion protocol?

Comment: I would add countries to that list. If you suddenly see a spike in traffic from China, even if it's from 1000 different ip addresses, then you are getting scraped. IP blocking and honeypots might be helpful in that scenario.

Comment: @halfer, I ask it as I wanted to write an article on this topic. My intention was to get more points to the subject. Many site owners are anxious about data privacy, propieritaryty and similar things. Would you explain on "the robots exclusion protocol"?

Comment: Ah, I expect you're aware of it: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.

Comment: @halfer, I know it as the 'robots.txt file' policy. The `robots exclusion protocol` is just an unknown term to me.

Comment: Well, now you know [another name for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

As a first note; consider if its worthwhile to provide an API for bots for the future. If you are being crawled by another company/etc, if it is information you want to provide to them anyways it makes your website valuable to them. Creating an API would reduce your server load substantially and give you 100% clarity on people crawling you.

Second, coming from personal experience (I created web-crawls for quite a while), generally you can tell immediately by tracking what the browser was that accessed your website. If they are using one of the automated ones or one out of a development language it will be uniquely different from your average user. Not to mention tracking the log file and updating your .htaccess with banning them (if that's what you are looking to do).

Its usually other then that fairly easy to spot. Repeated, very consistent opening of pages.

Check out this other post for more information on how you might want to deal with them, also for some thoughts on how to identify them.

[How to block bad unidentified bots crawling my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942276/how-can-i-resist-bad-unidentified-bots-to-crawl-my-website)

Comment: thank you for `'making API' to spare bandwidth` and `consistent opening of pages`

Answer (score 1):

I would also add analysis of when the requests by the same people are made. For example if the same IP address requests the same data at the same time every day, it's likely the process is on an automated schedule. Hence is likely to be scraping...

Possible add analysis of how many pages each user session has impacted. For example if a particular user on a particular day has browsed to every page in your site and you deem this unusual, then perhaps its another indicator.

It feels like you need a range of indicators and need to score them and combine the score to show who is most likely scraping.

Comment: thank you for `analysis of when the requests by the same client are made` and for a suggestion to `scoring the indicatiors to calculate final value`.